# Computer won't boot after Lubuntu 20.04.5 LTS update

Tags: boot, updates, lubuntu

I have a system that won't boot after trying to reboot the system as prompted by the most recent(2022-11-16) Lubuntu 20.04.5 LTS update.

The only thing displayed when the computer tries to boot is '_'.

The system boots from a thumb drive and does not report any errors when the hard disk is scanned.

I am looking for the best guide or tool to repair this situation.

Comment: I had what I believe is the same problem. In my case at least, it seems to be from a bug in the new Linux kernel version 5.15.0-53. Try selecting the previous kernel version from the GRUB menu (in my case that was 5.15.0-52) and see if that helps.
I suspect the bug is NVIDIA-related. Hopefully, they'll have fixed it in a day or so.

Comment: Do you see a grub menu?  Does the mouse cursor work?  Have you tried to start a virtual terminal (crtl+alt+F4)?  Any proprietary video hardware (Nvidia,...)?  Is secure boot off, and Windows power option Fast Start off? A little more information would help us make reasonable suggestions.

Comment: The system has Radeon RX Vega 10 Graphics (Graphics Frequency 1400 MHz). 
 I have turned off fast boot, quiet boot, and secure boot.  When I boot with the thumb drive, the mouse works fine.  Graphics appear fine as well.  I can open a virtual terminal from the desktop (ctrl-alt-F4), but I am unclear as to the next step.  I believe dlanced is correct -- that I need roll back the kernel version.  I'm just not sure how to do that.  I also haven't had any luck using ctrl-alt-F1 on boot up to get a terminal to open.